# MTG MYSQL Table error with add_meta_data not properly functioning

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, dom, variables

I've omitted some of the code to make it easier to view. What it does is it pulls magic the gathering card list from an XML file and populates it to a mysql table. Once the table is populated for each card it automatically creates a post for each card and populates the data.

Most of the data to be inputted will be done via custom fields. Which everything as you see here works perfectly except one part in the custom fields area that I don't quite get.

Wordpress Codex lists custom fields like this:

```
<?php add_post_meta($post_id, $meta_key, $meta_value, $unique); ?>
```

Example

```
 <?php add_post_meta(68, '_color', 'red', true); ?>
```

None of my custom fields work except for one which is:

```
$meta($post_id, 'Condition', 'M/NM', true);
```

As for the other custom fields that do not work they all contain variables like so:

```
$meta($post_id, 'Rating', $rating, true);
```

I've tried several different methods without success. There are plenty of examples on the net where variables have been used in add_meta_data, so I just haven't been able to find why it is not correctly working. This has bogged me down the past 2 days. Any ideas?

Plus, how in the world do you attach a photo as the featured image for that post?

```
<?php
    $z = new xmlreader;
    $z->open('http://***.com/wp-content/themes/***/mtg/arb.xml'); 
    $doc = new DOMDocument;

    while ($z->read() && $z->name !== 'card');

    echo "<table border=1>
    <tr>
        <td><div class='id'>ID</div></td>

    </tr>";

    $prodName = boutique_product_name('offer');
    $esc_html_e = esc_html_e('Add to cart','Boutique');
    while ($z->name === 'card')

    {

        $node = new SimpleXMLElement($z->readOuterXML());

        echo "<tr>
        <td><div class='id1'>".$node->id."</div></td>

        $name           =   $node->name;
        $rarity         =   $node->rarity;
        $manacost       =   $node->manacost;
        $ability        =   $node->ability;
        $pricing_high       =   $node->pricing_high;


        $mtg_post = array();
        $mtg_post['post_title'] = wp_strip_all_tags($name);
        $mtg_post['post_content'] = wp_strip_all_tags($ability);
        $mtg_post['post_status'] = 'publish';
        $mtg_post['post_author'] = 1;
        $mtg_post['post_type'] = 'post';
        $mtg_post['post_category'] = array(89,90);
        $mtg_post['comment_status'] = 'closed';
        $mtg_post['ping_status'] = 'closed';        

        $post_id = wp_insert_post( $mtg_post );

        $meta = add_post_meta;


        $meta($post_id, 'Mana Cost', $manacost, true); 
        $meta($post_id, 'Rarity', $rarity, true); 
        $meta($post_id, 'Condition', 'M/NM', true); 
        $meta($post_id, 'Price', $pricing_high, true); 

        echo "<td><a href=\"#$prodName\" class=\"add-to-cart et-shop-item\">\"$esc_html_e\"</a></td>";

        $z->next('card');
    }
    echo "</table>";
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured it out. So if anyone else runs into this same problem, here's the fix.

The variables that are within add_post_meta must be contained within double quotes and it will only work with a complex syntax.

Example below:

```
$meta = add_post_meta;

$meta($post_id, 'Flavor', "{$flavor}");
```